# Extjs action column and row editor plugin

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I've an Ext JS 5 grid with an action column with 3 items. I've configured also the row editor plugin. I need to change the enable/disable property of each items depend edit mode.

Here my code:

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
dataIndex: 'document',
text: 'Document',
items: [
  {
    isDisabled: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
      //some stuff                            
    },
    handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
      //some stuff
    }
  },
  {
    isDisabled: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
      //some stuff                            
    },
    handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
      //some stuff
    }
  },
  {
    isDisabled: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
      //some stuff
    },
    handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
      //some stuff
    }
  }
]
```

I don't know how to customize the editRenderer of the column. Actually, on edit mode, all 3 items disappears.

Thanks a lot
Stefano

Comment: "I need to change the enable/disable property of each items depend edit mode." - not sure I get it right, you want to disable action column buttons (and keep it visible) when row in edit mode?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I need to control che buttons during the edit mode. For example:

NON EDIT MODE: 
 - Button 1 visible (or enabled)
 - Button 2 hidden (or disabled)

EDIT MODE:
 - Button 1 hidden (or disabled)
 - Button 2 visible (or enabled)

Thanks

Comment: I think easiest way is to add one button to action column `items`, and another button to action column `editor` (and fix its appearance).